# Custom auth in Laravel 5 with login and register in the same form

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

How can I do the same login and registration form in same page. Like pinterest.com
and login users immediately after registration.

I dont know how to do a Manual Authentication, just the default `Auth\AuthController`

I have this controller, model and view.. throw me errors
`MethodNotAllowedHttpException in compiled.php line 7717:`

**model: publish.php**

```
class Publish extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract{

    //
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'user_profiles';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

}
```

**controller: PublishController**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Publicar;
use Auth;
use Request;

class PublishController extends Controller {


    public function index()
    {

        return view('partials.loginCreate', compact('publish'));


    }


     public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
        {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }
```

**view: login.blade.php**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/publish/authenticate') }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('publish', 'PublishController@index');
Route::get('publish/authenticate', 'PublishController@authenticate');
Route::get('publishLogout', 'PublishController@destroy');
```

Comment: You'd have to adapt or rewrite the basic scaffolding that comes with the framework. There's not a magical no-code solution.

Comment: Post your routes.php file

Comment: thats all the custom login.. Throw errors

Comment: `$user = User::create(...)`, `Auth::login($user)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your route from

```
Route::get('publish/authenticate', 'PublishController@authenticate');
```

to

```
Route::post('publish/authenticate', 'PublishController@authenticate');
```

because you are posting some data when you are calling authenticate method but the route method you have chosen is get and hence you are getting MethodNotAllowed exception

Comment: solved thanx.. And how can i do.. The Login and registration Form Like pinterest

Comment: you need ajax for that if really interested in that I can post the code but I ask you to do some research